# Chapter Number and Heading Stacked and Center-aligned

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

I have created a list style (1., 1.1, 2., 2.1,....) that i have mapped to a style for my headers.

So for example, my header would show as follows: 1. Executive Summary (aligned left to the page)

now i wish to have the foll functionality. i wish to have the number 1 of my list style in the middle of the page and the text that follows on the next line, again aligned in the middle of the page.

So for example as follows:

```
                                      1

                              Executive Summary
```

Body Text -- Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsum

Is there any way i can achieve the functionality in Word.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with STYLEREF fields and a table.

I note however that you don't want the full stop in the actual heading (just in the header), so first modify your outline numbered style so that the numbering is just 1 not 1., and have it set to be centred and followed by nothing.  Your heading style should be formatted so that the paragraph alignment is centred (and set line spacing and before and after spacing that you want).

Then, in the main body apply your heading style which will you give you just the number centred in the page, then insert a manual line break (SHIFT and ENTER) to get "stacked" line for your heading text.

In your header, you'll be using 2 STYLEREF fields, one to show the number, and the second to show the heading text.

However, the paragraph text STYLEREF will pick up the manual line break and so the number will appear higher than the text.

So, to get your header text to line up with the number, insert it in a 2-column table with the cell vertical alignment set to Bottom.  In the first column, insert your STYLEREF field for your heading style, to show the number (ie it has the \n switch) and type your full stop.  In the second column, insert a standard STYLEREF field for your heading style.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tanya. i followed your instructions and this is what i have: [link](http://imgur.com/a/2YBZR)... i have a few queries.. first, im unable to line up my number and the string, exec summary as elegantly as you have in your example.. it's not centered right, and it's too close to the number... how do i fix this? i tried line space before option, but it doesn't work. Second, i'm not quite sure i got the part where you talk about the \n switch for the number in the header... can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: so i added some indent to get the number to be centered...[link](http://imgur.com/a/i5fbN) but my other queries still hold. namely, increasing the space between the numbers and the text. And \n switch bit. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry haven't checked messages earlier.  Looking at your screenshot, to get the number centred instead of indent, you just need to change the list numbering setup so that "Follow number with" is set to "Nothing" (instead of the default option of "Tab character").  The \n switch is added to the STYLEREF field code if you tick the box for field options "Insert paragraph number".